# My Chrome extension is not working after publishing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a basic Chrome extension that does a click when a class is found. It's working in developer mode where I load unpacked, but it doesn't work after publishing. It's supposed to show popup.html when clicked, but it shows the default menu you get when you right-click an icon.

I have uploaded all the files in the zip, and they are all the same files. Why is this happening?

Comment: surely such a chrome extension is so trivial and short you could possibly put the code in the question

Comment: Have you checked that the published version you're testing has the same version number as your unpacked version? When uploading a new package to the Web Store, it's fairly typical to have a delay of one to two hours between when you save it and when it becomes available.

Comment: Without [MCVE](/help/mcve) in the question or a link to the extension in the web store you're reducing our ability to answer. Currently we can only guess what's wrong, and this is not how programming, debugging, and helping out should normally work.